# getting RS Eevents category name from Joomla database

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to get the category details from the joomla database for RSEvents. Can anyone shed any light on why this isn't working:

```
function _getCategorySlug($value) {
    // Get a db connection.
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();    
    // Create a new query object.
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);    
    // Select all articles for users who have a username which starts with 'a'.
    // Order it by the created date.
    // Note by putting 'a' as a second parameter will generate `#__content` AS `a`
    $query
        ->select($db->quoteName(array('a.*', 'b.id', 'b.ide')))
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__categories', 'a'))
        ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__rseventspro_taxonomy', 'b') 
        . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.id') . ')')
        ->where($db->quoteName('b.ide') . ' = '.$db->quote($value));     
    // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
    $db->setQuery($query);   
    // Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
}
```

Comment: are you calling the function anywhere? Also ensure that you `return` something at the end of the function

Comment: oops forgot to return the results!

it didn't help though, here's what _getCategorySlug($event->id) returns:

`Unknown column 'a.*' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT `a`.`*`,`b`.`id`,`b`.`ide` FROM `db_categories` AS `a` INNER JOIN `db_rseventspro_taxonomy` AS `b` ON (`a`.`id` = `b`.`id`) WHERE `b`.`ide` = '41'`

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you. Using the below function you can get the categories of a particular event.

```
public function getCategories($id) {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->clear()
        ->select($db->qn('id'))
        ->from($db->qn('#__rseventspro_taxonomy'))
        ->where($db->qn('type').' = '.$db->q('category'))
        ->where($db->qn('ide').' = '.$id);

    $db->setQuery($query);
    return $db->loadColumn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! That was a great help and got me to where I need (with a little tweaking):

```
function getCategories($id) {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->clear()
        ->select($db->qn('id'))
        ->from($db->qn('#__rseventspro_taxonomy'))
        ->where($db->qn('type').' = '.$db->q('category'))
        ->where($db->qn('ide').' = '.$id);
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $categories = $db->loadColumn();
    return implode("_", $categories);
}
```

Also, would be great to find out what was wrong with my original query to get category's alias from the #__categories table